# playing Digital game online with my family member >

Tags: ps4, dragon-ball-fighterz

I share digital games with brother. I bought Dragon Ball Fighterz and shared it with him. We went to play an online game because we live in different city. When we were are in the same lobby and create match we have an error message "No Room", but when he played with someone else the match worked. Is it because we are using the same game?

Comment: Do you both use the same PSN account to play the shared games, are you using SharePlay (though I don't think this works for multiplayer anyways), or do you each have a seperate PSN account you use?

Comment: we are using http://ca.ign.com/wikis/playstation-4/How_to_Game-Share_with_Family_and_Friendsg and my account ps+ my brother account regular

Comment: Do you both have PS+?  Chances are good that's what's going to be the problem.

Comment: I have the PS+ my bother don't have PS+. it seem  we have problem playing on same copy.